# How to change MXD name?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have a finished project but I have to make another with any information first (mostly) and I want to make a copy of the first draft and I just want to rename the mxd in my arcgis 10.1. Is there any way to do this without altering the project?

Comment: It sounds like you just need to make a copy of the MXD file, rename it, and work from there. Keep the old MXD as your draft copy. This should be done while ArcGIS is closed.

Comment: Make a copy of the document?  If the data will remain the same in your other projects but are located in different areas, you can use the bookmark function to save different areas.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this.

Firstly, in Windows Explorer, select the MXD, copy and paste it and rename it appropriately as was mentioned in the comments by @DanC and @Goldring.

Another way would be to open the MXD in ArcGIS, in the File menu, choose Save As... and rename it appropriately.

Finally, you could use the python console and type the following:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(path_to_your_mxd)
```

or, if you have your map open, type

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('Current')
```

Then type:

```
mxd.saveACopy(path_to_your_new_mxd)
```

Of course, there are other ways, but these should suffice.